# How to mount a directory with submounts via mount(2) function?

Tags: c, bind, mount

I'm curious about mount(2) function.

```
 int mount(const char *type, const char *dir, int flags, void *data)
```

Is there any equivalent way to "mount --rbind olddir newdir" to mount with sub-mount ?

Let's say.

```
/origin/A (mount --bind /tmp /origin/A )
/new (mount --bind /origin /new)
```

In this case, /new/A doesn't display files in /tmp.
So, new directory should be bind with the following command.

```
$ mount --rbind /origin /new
```

I wonder if there is a same way via `mount` function in C program like '-rbind'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there was MS_REC flag for mount() function.